# How can use prefetch_related to select deep object in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Assuming these as Django model for the sake of simplicity:

```
class A():
    a = ForeignKey('B')

class B():
    b = ForeignKey('C')

class C():
    c = CharField()
```

Assume I have list of `C` and I want to get list of `B` related to `C`'s AND list of `A` related to this list of `B`'s in one query. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I can do this action and try some methods but I want optimized method

Comment: This site is designed to get help after you've tried something yourself. It's highly recommended you post any code you've tried, even if it doesn't work or you don't think it's as efficient as it could be.